# Can't show image from s3 in React Native using Amplify Storage API

Tags: image, react-native, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I'm simply trying to show an image from an s3 bucket using AWS Amplify's storage and react native. My code is the following:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  state = { fileUrl: '' }

  componentDidMount() {
        Storage.get('vlad-tchompalov-450777-unsplash.jpg')
          .then(data => {
            console.log("data: ", data)
            this.setState({
              fileUrl: data
            })
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log("error fetching image", err)
          })
      }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      { this.state.fileURL != '' && console.log('state: ', this.state.fileUrl) &&
        <Image source={{ uri: this.state.fileUrl }} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
      }
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

From the console.log() I DO get the proper URL of the photo (if I click it I can see the photo) and it has https, so that shouldn't be the problem:
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bey4M.png)

I didn't add access level to the API call so it defaults to 'public' which is what I need.

I checked the configuration and permissions and seems to be OK.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it's a stupid suggestion, but have you tried without calling that console.log('state...')? Cause I don't know how it is evaluated. In other words simply `{ this.state.fileURL != '' &&
        <Image ... /> }`

Comment: `Boolean(console.log('hello'))` is `false`

Comment: can you add your code on to jsfiddle?
Did you paste your image URL in browser to know that URL fetches the image correctly?

Comment: @Milore that was the problem! It works now! It's weird because I added the console.log because it wasn't working, but then I fixed some configuration and left that console.log. Anyway, thanks!!

Comment: Glad to hear it works :)

Comment: Can I post it as an answer to make order?

Comment: @Milore shure! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console.log('state: ', this.state.fileUrl)
```

always represents a falsy value, so

```
<Image source={{ uri: this.state.fileUrl }} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
```

will never be considered and added to the render method. Removing it will fix the bug. Simply like:

```
{ this.state.fileURL != '' && <Image ... /> }
```